# How do I understand math equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question

Comment the basic math requisites for interpreting math formulae in this way

**Waves**

$$f = {1 \over T}$$

We are dividing 1 into T equal parts and one part corresponds to the frequency

**Magnification ( Ray Optics)**

$$m = {h' \over h}$$

h' corresponds to the size of image and h to the size of object. and We are dividing h'into h equal parts and each partition will gives us the what multiple is h'comparing h.

Comment: There's not really much of a question to be answered here. The answer is just to study and think, and do that for a long time.

Comment: With waves, I think that the frequency times the wavelength equals some constant.  e.g. speed of light, or the fundamental period of a sine function.  When I see $\frac {h'}{h},$ I see of  growth rates (as a percentage) and I think of applications in economics, it is also a formula for "elasticity" .  It is also a "logarithmic derivative"

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one and only one way to understand any statement in mathematics. For instance, I could instead interpret $1/T$ as the number which when multiplied by $T$ gives the number $1$. In some contexts, this perspective is much more enlightening that the notion of dividing a quantity into groups of a fixed size.

As you study more mathematics, you will be exposed more and more ways of thinking about different equations and identities. Over time, you develop an intuition for what perspective seems more helpful for understanding certain situations, but more often than not, there will be more than one valid way to reckon any given statement.